# Problem with device orientation code in Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, html

The following code is supposed to make a map on a web page be the only element that is displayed on the page when the phone is turned sideways, and then re-adds the other elements when the phone is turned back to it's original portrait orientation. **This works in Chrome for Android but does not work in FireFox v39 for Android**. The first alert fires in FireFox, so I know that device orientation is supported, but the second alert never fires in FireFox, so there is something wrong with my second conditional.

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
        alert("supported");
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function (eventData) {
            if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
                alert("90 or -90");
                $("#mapTop").css("display", "none");
                $("#mapBottom").css("display", "none");
            }
            else {
                $("#mapTop").css("display", "block");
                $("#mapBottom").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Try this to see if window.orientation has some values in FF (I dont know and I cant test it for you. The following code should work.)

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    alert("supported");
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function (eventData) {
        alert(window.orientation)
    });
}
```

I'd suggest you to use `eventData.alpha`, `eventData.beta`, `eventData.gamma` properties to determine orientation as described here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent